# Web based P2P applications

Tags: webapp-rec

Are there any safe (secure) web apps available that will allow you to do P2P sharing?  Before anyone asks no i am not referring to pb or anything of that nature, however something that could be a limewire replacement in the web would be most close to what I am seeking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

p2p normally means endpoint to endpoint. webapps run on the server / the cloud, a user connects to the services through a browser.

so, real peer 2 peer will be a bit .. strange with browser-server.

to establish a session between end points (through firewalls) you have to have a central instance which helps to establish the connection. i do not think that this kind of help could be called "webapplication".

anyway, some things look promising:

- [opera unite](http://unite.opera.com/) is browser 2 browser
- websockets could be user to initiate a browser 2 browser connection
- iirc, flash supports p2p as well (eg. http://zattoo.com transfers their video stuff via p2p flash).

Answer (score 1):

put.io is invite only right now but is basically a web based torrent client.  Works with rapidshare links as well.

Comment: but just because that service downloads stuff to its servers does not make it "web based p2p", imho. it is just cloud-storage with a nice method to fill it up :)